# Caliburn.Micro - pass readonly properties to view model

Tags: model-view-controller, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro, readonly

in my Windows Phone 8.1 application I'm working with images (cropping, applying filters etc.) thus I need controls' readonly values such as ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset or Canvas.ActualWidth in my view model.

How can I pass such values to the view model with Caliburn.Micro? When they are readonly, I can't access them in the xaml.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is example with Loaded event, you can use better event for your use

```
micro:Message.Attach=[Event Loaded] = [Action LoadCanvasProperties($this.ActualWidth, $this.ActualHeight)]"
```

Comment: add this to your canvas element and implement LoadCanvasProperties(double width, double height) method

Comment: Ok, thanks! Good idea. For ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset I guess I can use ViewChanged event.